# postback disabled button asp.net nvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do this one http://jquerywall.com/demo-multi-transfer-jquery-ui-selectable/
But the problem is that this multiselect plugin has some buttons.When i click any of these buttons my page gets posted and goes to its methods.
Here are my buttons

```
<div id="transfer-buttons">
           <button id="add-button">Add &rarr;</button>
           <button id="add-all-button">Add All *&rarr;</button>
           <button id="remove-button">&larr; Remove</button>
           <button id="remove-all-button">&larr;* Remove All</button>  

         </div>
```

here are my buttons functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#add-button").click(add);
        $("#add-all-button").click(addAll);
        $("#remove-button").click(remove);
        $("#remove-all-button").click(removeAll);
        $("#source-list, #target-list").selectable();
        addHiglightPlugin();
    });
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `type="button"` attribute to your buttons. When `<button>` has no type specified it acts like a submit button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

The other thing you can do is [prevent default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) in your event handlers:

```
function add(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // your code here
}
```